# Select JRE version for my applet

Tags: java, applet

For my applet I have some authentication problems because of that I have to run applet with Java 6. but If users have latest versions than Java 6, Applet will not work. It's blocked by java security. 
[Oracal doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-141751.html) says that

```
<param name="java_version" value="1.6">
```

using this We can control java version for Applet
I used it for my Applet and test,
With Java 8 and Java 6 in my machine but still it's blocked

How can I change java version for my applet

Answer (score 1):

JRE 1.6.0_95 (that isn't public) is required, because of 1.8.0_45 JRE Security Baseline.

[Deploying Java Applets With Family JRE Versions in Java Plug-in for Internet Explorer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/family-clsid-140615.html)